# Django FileField - not stored on disk?

Tags: python, django, apache

I have django file upload application. I have a model looking like this:

```
class BaseFile(Model):
    input_name = CharField( max_length = 132 )
    content = FileField( upload_to = "%Y/%m/%d" )
    upload_time = DateTimeField( auto_now_add=True )
    owner_group = CharField( max_length = 32 , default = None )
```

In the `settings.py` file I have set:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = "/tmp/storage"
```

When I use this with the development server things seem to work, I can upload files and if I go to the `/tmp/storage` directory I can see the `%Y/%m/%d` directories created and populated with my files.

When I try this using Apache and mod_wsgi things also seem to work:

1. The HTTP POST returns status 200.
2. A subsequent GET will return the files in question.

But - when I go the `/tmp/storage` directory there are no directories/files to be found and if I stop and start Apache the GET will fail with IOError:

`No such file: /tmp/storage/2017/11/27/FILEX_Z1OZMf8`

So - it seems to me that Django keeps the files in memory when using `mod_wsgi`?

I am using 100% default Django settings when it comes to storage backend. I see no errors in the Apache log.

Comment: Can you please check permissions for `/tmp/storage/` directory

Comment: Storing things in /tmp/ seems like a bad idea anyway; it is usually cleared when the machine is restarted.

Comment: I have made the `/tmp/storage` directory `o+rwx`- and mind it works when using the Django runserver.

Comment: It will of course not be in `/tmp` for the future - that was just in the debugging phase.